# How to insert into file using unix command?

Tags: c, unix, command

I want to insert into file using unix command

```
New_IP=New_IP=strtok(Network_config,delimeter);
system("sed -i ' i '$New_IP'  ' Network_settings.txt");
```

Comment: Are you asking help with `sed` command, or help with passing parameters in C to `system()` call? If `sed` is not the problem, please add to question the command line command which does what you want, and ask "how to do this system() call from C". Or if your problem is creating a command line command which does what you want, then ask that, instead of asking a C question.

Comment: I want to insert into file using sed command  that is the value stored in New_IP into the file

Comment: So what is the problem with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

It's safest to pass values like this to command line as environment variables, and let shell expand them. This avoids a ton of string escaping hassle. So maybe:

```
New_IP=strtok(Network_config,delimeter);
setenv("New_IP", New_IP);
system("sed -i \" i $New_IP  \" Network_settings.txt"); 
/* note backshaled \" in string above are for C compiler */
```

Note: if `New_IP` accidentally contains newlines, above will not work, because *sed* wants those escaped with backslash, when using *sed* `i` command. Also, allowing newlines will allow input to have more sed commands, which might do something nasty, for example with sed `w` command. So `New_IP` should definitiley be sanitized for *sed*, but fortunately that's much simpler than sanitizing for shell, which can be avoided by using env variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use `$New_IP` in the C string like you do in other script languages.

In c you have to insert your variable in this way for example

```
char *command;

asprintf(command, "sed -i ' i '%s'  ' Network_settings.txt", New_IP);
system(command);
free(command) // if command is useless in your code then free it
```

Comment: Note: this will not work if `New_IP` contains any whitespace, and will actually be a security vulnerability, if New_IP is not 100% trusted value (imagine if it contained `"; rm -rf ~ #"`)